# Adjusting MediaController source issues

Tags: android

I'd like to adjust layout in standard MediaController class.For that I downloaded it's source file from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/MediaController.java). It seems to be easy to tweak layouts, however I have problems with the following lines:

[127](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/MediaController.java#127) - Here eclipse says it can't find PolicyManager - doesit mean I have to download it too ? I guess there must another solution for that.

[416](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/widget/MediaController.java#416) - Here it wants to cast like that ((Object) 
 event).isDown(), which is strange and doesn't solve anything.

Any suggestions're welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 127 - Here eclipse says it can't find PolicyManager - doesit mean I have to download it too ? I guess there must another solution for that.

[PolicyManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/com/android/internal/policy/PolicyManager.java) is a class under package `com.android.internal` in APIs.

> 416 - Here it wants to cast like that ((Object) event).isDown(), which is strange and doesn't solve anything.

[KeyEvent.isDown()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/view/KeyEvent.java#KeyEvent.isDown%28%29) is annotated as `Hide` in APIs.

Generally speaking, the development API (android.jar) that google provides to consumer developer has the internal (com.android.internal) and hidden (@hide) APIs stripped off. However, the runtime  API (framework.jar) that installed on the actual device has everything.

If you want to use these internal and hide API in your code, the solution is to use either reflection or the workaround inazaruk explained in his blog [here](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you mean as a developer with SDK installed I can't use it directly, but compiled apk on users' devices gonna have this access? Thanks for the suggestion-gone reading.